# Gas estimation error with Chainlink and Remix

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink, kovan

I am working on a project that will need to use ChainLink to make external API calls from the Ethereum blockchain. I was testing out the [demo code](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) like so:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8;
        jobId = "d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
```

However, I am consistently running into a `Gas estimation error` after deploying and trying to call `requestVolumeData`.

What am I doing wrong?

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mCaq8RCxlZPN-XJcO9kKzghWAiL-j2gW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gas estimation error` is a common error meaning that you don't have enough of "something" to send your transaction, maybe it's layer 1 (ETH) gas, or an ERC20 token like LINK (technically, erc677, but I digress...)

Whenever you work with a Chainlink feature that uses the [request and receive](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-request-model/) method of using chainlink, you need to [fund the consumer contract with LINK token](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/).

The issue here is you sent LINK to the oracle address and not the address of your deployed contract.

[image: Contract Address]

If you copy the address of your deployed contract and send the LINK there, it should work for you.